# Cannot see retransmission packet from client to server

Tags: c#, sockets, wireshark, retransmit-timeout, tcp-keepalive

I have a custom client-server application both running on LAN(OS-Windows8). I used keep-alive option in the client and I see Keep alive packets in Wireshark. However, when I unplug the network cable of the machine the server is running on, I do not see any retransmission packets from my client to server but I see other applications sending retransmission packets to the server's IP.
I don't understand why this is happening. Do I need to explicitly set retransmit timeout value or how else can I solve this issue?

For reference, this is the keep-alive code I am using.
[How to implement TCP KeepAlive in VB.NET on a TCP Client(socket)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292593/how-to-implement-tcp-keepalive-in-vb-net-on-a-tcp-clientsocket)

I am calling setKeepAlive with values-  SetKeepAlive(clientSocket, 60000, 10000)

Thank you